# fixed bottom right but left top will be in the same axis

Tags: css, position, fixed

I want to make a div which is fixed on the bottom and right but top margin and left margin will always be 100px from the browser! It is very weird I know but I coulndt do it. Maybe it needs a javascript? or can I make it with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, just set `left` and `top` to the margin you need.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLfXU/)

**JS**

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: One more question how can I avoid to get rid of red area? I mean when i make the browser more narrow I start to see it! maybe its better to see the photo bigger but cropped from corners. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/z9FNU/

Comment: No this red is to show you the area. What I want is when I make the window very narrow I want the photo to stay in full background in that red div I hope it make sense.

Comment: So you want the photo stretched, breaking aspect ratio?

Comment: I don't want photo to be stretched. I want the photo keep the ratio even the screen is big/small or the browser is full or totally narrow.

Comment: Then you want to make it so the photo will be offscreen but keep aspect ratio when it's really narrow?

Comment: yes like that http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php but in our example http://jsfiddle.net/z9FNU/

Comment: Here it is using the background cover technique as in the css-tricks link http://jsfiddle.net/z9FNU/2/

Answer (score 1):

Media queries.  Learn to use and love them.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    div {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-height: 300px) {
    div {
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L35cE/